# How do we mock private method using jasmine?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

Trying to mock private method that is in the class could not get any success, I am using jasmine so in below code i have `getDrug` method that is making http call , Now i can mock core but how do i stub/mock getDrug so code coverage can be improve.

DrugPriceApi.node.ts

```
export class DrugPriceApi extends Types.ModuleBase < DrugPriceParam, DrugPriceResultSet[] > {

        private _memberId: string = "";
        private _dependencies: any;
        private errorMessage: string = "There was an issue while retrieving drug price. Please try again.";

        before(args: DrugPriceParam): Promise < DrugPriceParam > {
            args.daysSupply = args.daysSupply ? args.daysSupply : args.appName === "VOYA" ? "90" : "BLNK";
            return Promise.resolve(args);
        }

        core(args: DrugPriceParam, requestMethod: Interface.Core.RequestMethod, _dependencies: any): Promise < any > {
                this._dependencies = _dependencies;

                return new Promise < any > ((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
                        this.getDrug(function(resolve) {
                                resolve( //response here);});
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

                private getDrug(args: DrugPriceParam, requestMethod: Interface.Core.RequestMethod) {
                    return requestMethod.http.makeRequest({
                        url: {
                            name: 'domain_getDrug',
                            params: {
                                version: '1.0',
                                appName: args.appName ? args.appName : 'WEB',
                                tokenId: args.tokenId,
                                refId: args.refId,
                                internalID: args.memberInfo.internalID,
                                searchText: args.drugName,
                                drugNdcId: 'BLNK'
                            }
                        },
                        body: {
                            memberInfo: args.memberInfo
                        }
                    });
                }
```

DrugPriceApi.spec.ts

```
       import {
            DrugPriceApi
        } from "./DrugPriceApi.node";

        it("should get drugByName", function(done) {
            let getDrug: any;
            beforeEach((done) => {
                function getMockData(url: string): Promise < any > {
                    const rtnval = {
                        "details": [],
                        "header": {
                            "statusDesc": "Success",
                            "statusCode": "0000",
                            "IndexOfRequestThatFailed": []
                        }
                    };

                    return Promise.resolve(rtnval);
                }

                let moderator: Interface.Mock.Handler = {
                    getMockData: getMockData
                };
                getDrug = moderator;

            });
            let param: any;
            param.daysSupply = "BLNK";
            param.quantity = "BLNK";
            param.memberId = "1372";
            const result: any = _sdkInstance.SDK.Pricing.getDrugPrice(param);
            result.then(function(res: any) {
                spyOn(DrugPriceApi.prototype, "core").and.callFake(() => {
                        expect(DrugPriceApi.prototype.getDrug).toHaveBeenCalled();
                });
                expect(res.Header.StatusCode).toBe("5000");
                done();
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused on what is happening here and why DrugPriceApi is being tested indirectly. It looks like we are testing Pricing.getDrugPrice instead of the DrugPriceApi.

If you want to test DrugPriceApi.core then you simple needs to create an instance of it and set DrugPriceApi.getDrug = jasmine.createSpy();

```
const api = new DrugPriceApi();
api.getDrug = jasmine.createSpy();
api.core(...whatever).then(() => {
    expect(api.getDrug).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```